# Dojo GridX with row headers or rowspan?

Tags: dojo, dojo.gridx

Is it possible to user Dojo GridX with some kind of row headers or rowspan?

I want to present the hierarchical (2-level) structure in the grid - a grouping item has some subitems, such like:

```
---------------------------|
|             | Address 1  |
| Customer 1  |------------|
|             | Address 2  |
---------------------------|
|             | Address 1  |
| Customer 1  |------------|
|             | Address 2  |
---------------------------|
```

In pure HTML it's one of the methods described in http://www.pdprogrammeur.com/tables-and-html5-table/ but for Dojo GridX I couldn't find any such example.

Is such functionality supported in GridX? If so, how to use it?

Comment: Ive looked for such function myself and was unable to find it :-(

Comment: When set up your 'structure' of the grid, I believe you can have multiple arrays: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html
So you might do `var layout = [[address1],[address2]];` in some fashion. Also consider multi-rowed rows: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#multi-rowed-rows

Answer (score 2):

The colspan is not available for gridx, we may plan to implement it in the future version.

Comment: You're a GridX team member? Is there a ticket for that change? If so, it would be an answer (documented on script :)